# reading int from text line by line

Tags: java, arrays, file

i have a 3 lines text of int that are data i need to put in some variables, i want to access one by one to all like an array, i can read the firt line but don't know how to go to next line, i know it 's a stupid thing but i'm blocked

```
public void Load () throws IOException {
    BufferedReader   in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("prova.txt"));

    String inputLine = in.readLine();
    String [] fields = inputLine.split(" "); // Splits at the space
    int i=0;
    while(inputLine!=null) {
    System.out.println(fields[i]); //prints out name
    i++;
    }

}
```

i wanto to access to a single int for any line, any tips?

Comment: use a while loop on `in.readLine()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a large text file line by line using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)

Comment: How does that input text file look like?

Comment: text look like this:
1 12   23 
12  34   56  78  90
12 45  78  90 34 54

Answer (score 3):

You can get all lines from file using [`Files.readAllLines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) from java8:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("prova.txt"));

for (String line : lines) {
    String[] split = line.split(" "));
    // use element access by index to do what you want
}
```

Also if you are familiar with stream api:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("prova.txt"))
        .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Java NIO API.

```
Path myPath = Paths.get("prova.txt")
List<String> contents = Files.readAllLines(myPath)
for(String line : contents) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: thx , i know about this, but don't know how to acess to a single int, like i want to do something with firts elemnt of firt line , something with elemnt 4 o 3rd line :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate twice : once over the lines in the files (for example using `Files.lines(...)`) and then over the fields in the line (with say a `for` loop).
Something like so :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Snippet().Load();
    }

    public void Load() throws IOException {
        Files.lines(new File("prova.txt").toPath()).forEach(line -> {
            String[] fields = line.split("\\s"); // Splits at the space
            for (String field : fields) {
                System.out.println(field);
            }
            System.out.println();
        });

    }
}
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

What wrong you are doing is that you have read only first line and trying to print all that is there in first line by continuously increasing value of **i** which will end up with null pointer exception.I have tried the same way you are doing it. Let me know if you have any concern.

```
public class Snippet {
public static void Load() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("prova.txt"));

    String inputLine = in.readLine();
    // Splits at the space

    while (inputLine != null) {
        int i = 0;
        String[] fields = inputLine.split(" ");
        while (i < fields.length) {
            System.out.println(fields[i]); // prints out name
            i++;
        }
        inputLine = in.readLine();
    }

}
```

}

What i am doing here is reading each line splitting it based on space and print everything that came on first line and and then read next line at the end of loop.